# Scanning an xml file once or twice?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file to be transformed by XSLT. It has two kinds of tags, say X1 and X2 tags, randomly positioned in the XML file. I need the results of the X1-processing in element E1, and then, following this element E1, a second element E2 with the processing results of the X2 tags.
So the XML file looks like:

```
<root>
 ...
<X1/>
 ...
<X2/>
 ...
<X1/>
 ...
<X1/>
 ...
<X2/>
 ...
etc.
</root>
```

and the result file:

```
<root1>
<E1>
<x1/>
<x1/>
<x1/>
</E1>
<E2>
<x2/>
<x2/>
</E2>
</root1>
```

Question: can I do all this in ONE go, or do I need to loop through the input files twice?
(The reality is more complex, but this is the fundamental question).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to wrap all the `X1` inside an `E1` and all the `X2` inside an `E2`? If that is what you want it can be done in one go.

Comment: Do you also want the element names in lowercase? And are they empty or are they nodes containing more data, elements, text?

Comment: it is just to indicate that Xn elements are processed.

Answer (score 3):

This stylesheet will give you the result you expect, for the example you posted with the data you have as input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="x1" select="//X1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="x2" select="//X2"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root1>
            <E1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$x1"/>
            </E1>
            <E2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$x2"/>
            </E2>
        </root1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="X1">
        <x1><xsl:apply-templates/></x1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="X2">
        <x2><xsl:apply-templates/></x2>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The variables gather *all* `X1` and `X2` elements and store them in variables. The template that matches `root` buids a new structure and copies the `X1` and `X2` nodes under `E1` and `E2`. The other templates replace `X1`/`X2` for `x1`/`x2`.

If they didn't have to be lowercase, you could just use `<xsl:copy>`:

```
<xsl:template match="X2|X1">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="X2|X1">
    <xsl:element name="{lower-case(name())}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 1.0 you would need to use this for the lowercase

```
translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Actually, since the `root` template selects exactly which nodes you are interested in, you don't have to do it again in each template and can use `*`:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{lower-case(name())}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hmm.... seems to me that first all X1 elements are processed, and then all X2, so it's scanning twice.
Maybe it must scan an element, decide if it's X1 or X2, and then apply the appropriate X1 or X2 template. An d then on to the next element. But then the result won't go in the appropriate element E1 or E2....

Comment: It does reads the nodes twice, but from memory. It doesn't scan the files twice. It loads the file in a DOM tree, and then uses XPath to select the nodes and store them in variables, and then traverses the DOM tree processing templates that match the nodes.

Comment: Does XSLT 2 also read the **entire** tree, if the tree spans multiple input XML files, via an index file containing a list of those XML files?

Comment: @Erik, both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 work with a processing and data model where each input document is completely parsed into a tree first and that tree then serves as the input to any transformation. XSLT 3.0 which is under development tries to define streaming http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#streaming-concepts to avoid the memory consumption for very large documents while allowing the use of XSLT/XPath. I think http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-fork could help in your case but I don't know whether any of the XSLT 3.0 processors already implement that.